# SVN Multiple Repository in One Folder

Tags: svn

We have a project that linked with repository from url `https://x.x.x.x:xxxx/svn/project1` with the following directories like below :

```
./src
   /be 
   /da
   /bl
```

Than, i want add folder (let say folder "lib") and checkout from different url, let say `https://x.x.x.x:xxxx/svn/project2/lib`. The folder structure like bellow :

```
./src -> https://x.x.x.x:xxxx/svn/project1
   /be -> https://x.x.x.x:xxxx/svn/project1/be
   /da -> https://x.x.x.x:xxxx/svn/project1/da
   /bl -> https://x.x.x.x:xxxx/svn/project1/bl
   /lib -> https://x.x.x.x:xxxx/svn/project2/lib
```

How we can update and commit with multiple repository?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do **The Right Things** in **The Right Way** (or at least read error-message - you modified something in `lib`, but not select `lib` for commit)

In common case nested, but unrelated Working Copies are **The Bad Idea** in SVN. You have to go by pure SVN-way: add lib as SVN externals to parent repository

Comment: this the right way, using external source solved my problem